# Database.query not working with RecordTypeId

Tags: apex, lightning, database

I'm making a call to db to retrieve the RecordTypeId from a record of an Object (both values passed as parameters in the function).

The point is that when I'm trying to save the code it gives me this error:

[image]

And my code looks like these:

```
List<SObject> recordL = Database.query('SELECT RecordTypeId FROM ' + sObjectName + ' WHERE Id = :recordId');
if(recordL.isEmpty() || recordL[0].RecordTypeId == NULL){
    return null;
}
```

**Does anyone know how to fix this or what's the problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic type `sObject` has no field `RecordTypeId`. Not all sObjects have record types. For that reason, you cannot access the field directly.

Since you don't know the sObject name at compile time, you can't cast it, e.g.

```
if(recordL.isEmpty() || ((Account)recordL[0]).RecordTypeId == null) {
```

so you'll need to use the generic `get()` method:

```
if(recordL.isEmpty() || recordL[0].get('RecordTypeId') == null) {
```

Note that you're going to get an exception if you try to execute this dynamic query against an object without record types.

Comment: Yeah, I have put logic to avoid objects without the field but I didn't know why this wasn't working. Thanks for your help!